# How to set up Grafana so that no password is necessary to view dashboards

Tags: grafana

Despite these settings, Grafana still requires the use of a password to view Dashboards. Can someone please help me with the correct settings?

```
[auth.anonymous]
# enable anonymous access
enabled = true

[auth.basic]
enabled = false
```

Comment: this change work but the user can navigate and view all the dashboards, I just want them to view via link, any extra setting required? embed option works but from the port 3000 they can view all

Comment: See https://grafana.com/docs/auth/overview/#anonymous-authentication

Answer (score 89, accepted):

Thanks @Donald Mok for his answer; I just want to make it as clear as possible. In the Grafana interface you can create an organization. After that you can create some dashboards for this organization. So, there is a problem that you need to specify the organization for anonymous users. And it should be a real organization (for your Grafana). And anonymous users will be able to see only dashboards from this organization.

```
#################################### Anonymous Auth ##########################
[auth.anonymous]
# enable anonymous access
enabled = true

# specify organization name that should be used for unauthenticated users
org_name = ORGANIZATION
```

Comment: Is it possible for an anonymous user to see dashboards from multiple organizations?

Comment: This literally saved me :D

Comment: Keep in mind anonymous users in Grafana can access still some menu's today. Including Explore.

Comment: none of the answers work for me, i am still presented with login form, or if disable_login_form=true with *welcome to Grafana" message and no way past it. Grafana ver 7.3.0. My goal is yo never see login form period.

Comment: This still works and is documented here:
https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/grafana/#anonymous-authentication

Comment: To anyone else: remove the ; comment indicator at the beginning of the lines
I spent an embarrassingly long time trying to fix this

Comment: I'd like to add that this configuration could be overridden with environment variables to avoid editing config files (very useful with Docker) as explained here https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#override-configuration-with-environment-variables

Answer (score 33):

To setup login for anonymous users you need to make these small configuration changes in the default.ini/grafana.ini file (Grafana\conf).

1. **If you want to hide the login page do this configuration:**

   ```
   [auth]
   # Set to true to disable (hide) the login form, useful if you use OAuth
   #disable_login_form = false 
   disable_login_form = true
   ```

   Change `disable_login_form` to `true`.
2. **Enable anonymous access:**

   ```
   [auth.anonymous]
   # enable anonymous access 
   enabled = true
   ```
3. **Specify the organization:**

   ```
   # specify organization name that should be used for unauthenticated users
   org_name = YOUR_ORG_NAME_HERE
   ```
4. **Restart Grafana and you should be able to see the Grafana dashboard. If not, just change your org role from `Viewer` to `Editor`:**

   ```
   # specify role for unauthenticated users
   org_role = Editor
   ```

Comment: This is not working anymore

Comment: @Matteo , it been almost 4 year, i am not sure about this

Answer (score 12):

I had this issue, but the root cause in my case was a tiny mistake.
I checked the grafana.log file and found that:

> "2016/02/12 09:24:57 [middleware.go:62 initContextWithAnonymousUser()]
>   [E] Anonymous access organization error: 'Anonymous Org.':
>   Organization not found"

I changed the org_name in grafana.ini, and after restarting Grafana, things worked well as I intended.

I recommend you check your grafana.log file to see what's wrong with your configuration.

Answer (score 6):

First of all, in `grafana.ini` adjust the following values:

```
[auth.anonymous]
# enable anonymous access
enabled = true

# specify organization name that should be used for unauthenticated users
org_name = YOUR_ORG_NAME_HERE

# specify role for unauthenticated users
org_role = SOME_USER_NAME_HERE # e.g. Anonymous
```

Now, after restarting Grafana, log in and make sure there is another user than admin created. If not, create one. The values in the user creation dialogue are actually unimportant to achieve the task.

Finally, set the same organisation name under global orgs to match your `grafana.ini` value. Also, make sure the user you created has the role you set in `grafana.ini` (in my example the role would be "Anonymous").

Answer (score 6):

**First your configuration should look like this:**

```
[auth.anonymous]
# enable anonymous access 
enabled = true

# specify organization name that should be used for unauthenticated users
org_name = ORGANIZATION

# specify role for unauthenticated users
org_role = Viewer

[auth]
# Set to true to disable (hide) the login form, useful if you use OAuth
disable_login_form = true
```

**Then you need to make an organization on the Server Admin page on the Grafana website with the exact same name as you specified here:** `org_name = ORGANIZATION`

**If you then make a dasbhoard with some panels you can share the dashboard or a specific panel with `<iframe>`, you can find more info [here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/sharing/)**

Comment: ^ This was my issue. The config was ok but the `org_name` didn’t point to an existing organization. Creating it in the dashboard (or renaming the default one) did it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what i did for my Caddy proxy which uses ***client-cert*** auth already. Beware, this ***still*** exposes your datasource to the ***public***! Be sure to replace your@email.com with your email and the Caddy proxy ip in grafana.ini.

*Caddyfile*

```
grafana.****.***, gf.****.*** {
    tls your@email.com {
        clients /mnt/user/appdata/caddy/conf/ca.crt
    }

    proxy / http://10.0.1.39:3000 {
        transparent
        websocket
        insecure_skip_verify
        header_upstream X-WEBAUTH-USER "admin"
    }
}

gf-pub.****.*** {
    tls your@email.com

    proxy / http://10.0.1.39:3000 {
        transparent
        websocket
        insecure_skip_verify
        header_upstream X-WEBAUTH-USER "public"
    }
}
```

*grafana.ini*

```
[auth.proxy]
enabled = true
header_name = X-WEBAUTH-USER
header_property = username
enable_login_token = false
whitelist = 10.0.1.3 <-- Your Caddy IP
```

Answer (score 0):

Elaborating on Jimilian's answer for the special case that it is a completely fresh and empty Grafana which you would like to configure to work without any user management (e.g. local installation for a single user): in this case, the organization needs to be `Main org.` (including the trailing dot). This is also the default, so you will also be fine just omitting the `org_name` setting from your config file in that case.

Of course, in that case your anonymous user needs additional permissions. A complete configuration for this case might look like this:

```
[auth.anonymous]
enabled = true
org_role = Admin

[auth.basic]
enabled = false

[auth]
disable_login_form = true
```