# Make a Grafana anonymous login show a specific dashboard

Tags: grafana

I have a Grafana instance set up to use anonymous login as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33111835/278403). When I go to the Grafana instance's url it shows the main dashboard page from which I can choose a specific dashboard to view. Is there a way, without using other programs, to configure Grafana to show a specific dashboard instead of the main one?

From my research I understand that part of the solution is to use a playlist, and I can get the effect I want by going to a playlist url, e.g. myhost:3000/playlists/play/1, but I would like to configure it so that myhost:3000 shows that playlist.

There are a couple of ways to achieve this, but both require additional applications. One is to use a reverse proxy web server, [such as nginx](https://grafana.com/docs/installation/behind_proxy/), the other is [grafana-kiosk](https://github.com/grafana/grafana-kiosk). I suspect that the very existence of grafana-kiosk implies that what I want to do is not possible, but there's no harm in asking.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done without additional software.

- In Server Admin | Orgs
  Make sure you have at least one organisation (I think I renamed the default).
- In Server Admin | Settings
  Allow anonymous viewer (need to edit the .ini file for this)
  auth.anonymous
  enabled   True
  hide_version  false
  org_name  [your default org name]
  org_role  Viewer
- 'Star' the dashboard you want as default
- In Configuration | Preferences
  Set the Home dashboard for the organisation
  Set the Org name to to match the name above