# Grafana Docker Image: change default role for the Anonymous User

Tags: grafana

I'm running Grafana on localdev and I don't want to login with admin credentials all the time. To that end I have created the following docker-compose:

```
 version: "3"
 
 services:
 
   grafana:
     image: grafana/grafana:8.3.5
     ports:
       - "3010:3000"
     environment:
       - GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED=true
     volumes:
        ...
```

This works for allowing anonymous users to gain access but it's in view-only / read-only mode. I would like to enable god-mode for the anonymous user per:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51173858/863651

Is there some environment variable or something to that effect that allows me to achieve the desired result. I want to avoid introducing my own 'defaults.ini' just to set 'org_role = Editor'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Any config from the config file can be overriden by env variable. Syntax for env variable name: `GF_<CONF-SECTION>_<CONFIG-PROPERTY>` (BTW also `GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ENABLED` follows this syntax).

So config file section:

```
[auth.anonymous]
org_role = Editor
```

has env variable equivalent:

```
GF_AUTH_ANONYMOUS_ORG_ROLE=Editor
```