# Where is the the config file for settings in Grafana

Tags: grafana

I am a free Grafana cloud plan user.

I want to enable anonymous access to my dashboard.

I searched many places and found they all talked about changing the config file in code.
I cannot find where the config file is and it seems [everyone talks about the config files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33111835/how-to-set-up-grafana-so-that-no-password-is-necessary-to-view-dashboards) and knows where it is located. Also found this official document talks about how to [enable the anonymous access](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/configure-security/configure-authentication/grafana/#anonymous-authentication).

To me, it feels like I need to log into a console on the Grafana server, but I cannot find it.

How can I change the config file to enable anonymous access to my dashboard? Does it require a paid plan?

Comment: Grafana [Configuration file location](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#configuration-file-location) from their official documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to config file as free Grafana cloud user. Deploy own Grafana instance and then you will be able to customize config file.

Comment: thanks @Jan, so I need to purchase the service and then I can deploy  my own Grafana instance, correct?

Comment: @Franva no need to purchase service. You can self service OSS version - https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/

Comment: so that mean I need to have a server to host and run the private instance of Grafana, correct?

Comment: @Franva: that is correct - when you download an OSS version of a product, it's just software, and you have to provide the backend server(s) on which it runs. That generally costs money, though some cloud providers offer short-term free tiers.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone coming here from a search, my grafana.ini was in

```
/etc/grafana/grafana.ini
```

[More info on the config file location here](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/next/setup-grafana/configure-grafana/#configuration-file-location).

Answer (score 0):

If you deploy your own grafana instance, then ONLY you can find the grafana.ini config file.

Location: `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini`